# Cloadflare Return 'rec_id' For 1 'A' Record in a Zone : PHP

Tags: api, cloudflare

I have a PHP script that adds a new 'A' record to a Cloudflare zone, however, by default these new 'A' records are set as non-active by Cloudflare and now days you can not set them as active when creating them.

So, to edit the new record to set it as active, you need the 'A' records 'rec_id'. In this case action 'rec_load_all' can't be used as there are too many zone 'A' records and I don't think you can filter the request (could be wrong & would be good to be wrong). The zone needs to be filtered.

I have tried the following 'dns_get_rec_one' but it just returns 'NULL' with no error message:

```
    function returnId(){
    $request = array();
    $request['a'] = 'dns_get_rec_one';
    $request['tkn'] = $this->tkn;
    $request['email'] = $this->apiEmail;
    $request['z'] = 'domain.com';
    $request['name'] = 'sub.domain.com';

    $response = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html?' . http_build_query($request)), true);
}
```

Any ideas as I have little experience with API interactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have worked this out with some help.

When you make the CURL 'rec_new' call to Cloudflare the response includes the 'rec_id' for the new "A" record. This can then be used as the 'id' in the next CURL 'rec_edit' call to edit the record as being active.

The guys at Cloudflare support answer within 24hrs as well and are helpful.

Snippets from class bellow:

```
private function newSub(){
    $fields = array(
        'a' => 'rec_new',
        'tkn' => $this->tkn,
        'email' => $this->apiEmail,
        'z' => $this->domain,
        'type' => 'A',
        'name' => $this->subName,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'ttl' => 1
    );
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value){
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //execute post
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);        
    $response = json_decode($response,true);

    if(!$response || $response['result'] != 'success'){
        $responseError = $response['msg'];
        // ERROR Handling
    }else{
        // Set rec_id for from the nw A record
        $this->rec_id = $response['response']['rec']['obj']['rec_id'];  
        // Activate
        $this->makeActive();
    }
}

private function makeActive(){
    $request['a'] = 'rec_edit';
    $request['tkn'] = $this->tkn;
    $request['email'] = $this->apiEmail;
    $request['z'] = $this->domain;
    $request['id'] = $this->rec_id;
    $request['type'] = 'A';
    $request['name'] = $this->subName;
    $request['content'] = $this->content;
    $request['service_mode'] = '1';// Make active
    $request['ttl'] = '1';

    $response = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html?' . http_build_query($request)), true);
    //var_dump($response); die;
    if(!$response || $response['result'] != 'success'){
        $responseError = $response['msg'];
        // ERROR Handling 
    }
}
```

Hope that this helps someone.